# can I assign to an object across multiple lines in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I think I'm forgetting the term for this so a title edit would be welcome. What I'd like to do is assign multiple functions to my `$scope` object, like so:

```
    $scope.
      widgetDropped = (event, ui) ->
        (console.log "widget dropped")
      dragCallback = (event, ui) ->     # fails
        console.log("started drag")     # fails
```

So the first 3 lines compile fine, but adding in the last 2 lines causes the compile to fail. Messed with line continuation a bit, no luck. Is it possible to do this sort of multi-line object assignment in coffeescript?

Comment: are you familiar with coffeescript? I'm trying to assign dragCallback to the scope object without putting $scope in two places.

Comment: I'm still curious what you are looking for. Have you had a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$scope =
  widgetDropped : (event, ui) ->
    console.log "widget dropped"
  dragCallback : (event, ui) ->
    console.log "started drag"
```

After that you can call your functions:

```
$scope.widgetDropped()  # logs "widget dropped"
$scope.dragCallback()   # logs "started drag"
```

Here is [running example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%24scope%20%3D%0A%20%20widgetDropped%20%3A%20%28event%2C%20ui%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22widget%20dropped%22%0A%20%20dragCallback%20%3A%20%28event%2C%20ui%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22started%20drag%22%0A%0A%24scope.widgetDropped%28%29%0A%24scope.dragCallback%28%29).

If you prefer it, you can add braces for clarity:

```
$scope = {
  widgetDropped : (event, ui) ->
    console.log "widget dropped"
  dragCallback : (event, ui) ->
    console.log "started drag"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *extend* (i.e. set multiple properties at once) `$scope` like this:

```
$scope.widgetDropped = (event, ui) -> console.log "widget dropped"
$scope.dragCallback  = (event, ui) -> console.log("started drag")
```

then you're out of luck, there's nothing native to CoffeeScript for that. Various libraries offer functions for that though, [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)/[Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#extend) for example:

```
_($scope).extend(
    widgetDropped: (event, ui) -> console.log "widget dropped"
    dragCallback:  (event, ui) -> console.log("started drag")
)
```

[jQuery has one too](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

There are various forms of [destructured assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) that go the other way:

```
o = { where: 'is', pancakes: 'house?' }
{ pancakes } = o
# pancakes is now 'house?'
```

but no native merging techniques.

Comment: thanks; it looks like very coffeescript-ish syntax and it works on one line, but not two; seems odd that it doesn't work for two lines